# Recursively Adding Nodes to a custom TreeMap

Tags: java, data-structures

Hello I am attempting to build my own TreeMap data structure. I have an add method that passes a Key and Value, I then have another method called insert that will recursively add the node to the tree. I keep getting a stackoverflow error. 
I am unsure how to resolve this error I've re-written my insert method a few times and tried passing parent Nodes into the method. Can someone explain the logic behind what should be passed into the insert method or how my code may possibly still work?

Is the best option here to utilize recursion to add nodes to my tree? or can I accomplish the same thing with a while loop?

Any help is appreciated thank you!

```
public boolean add(K key, V value) 
{

 //root is declared as a class level variable in my Map class 

if (root == null) {

        curSize++;
        root = new Node(key, value);
        root.parent = null;
        return true;
    }
    //Creating a new Node with the passed arguments
    Node n = new Node(key, value);
    Node curNode = root;

//Calling insert method

    if (curNode.insert(n, curNode)) {
        curSize++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

protected boolean insert(Node curNode, K key, V value) {

        int result = key.compareTo(curNode.key);
        boolean x = false;

        if (curNode.L == null && result < 0) {
            curNode.L = new Node(key, value);
            x = true;
        }
        if (curNode.R == null && result > 0) {
            curNode.R = new Node(key, value);
            x = true;
        }
        if (result == 0)
            x = false;

        if (curNode.L != null && result < 0)
            insert(curNode.L, key, value);
        if (curNode.R != null && result > 0)
            insert(curNode.R, key, value);

        return x;

    }
//My Node class with its constructor, Insert method is inside this class.

 private class Node {
    public Node L;
    public Node R;
    public K key;
    public V value;
    public Node parent;

    public Node(K k, V v) {
        this.L = null;
        this.R = null;
        this.key = k;
        this.value = v;
    }
```

Comment: It might be helpful to include a main method that creates a tree, and inserts data and that shows your problem. See [mcve] for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation of insert() you have

```
insert(Node curNode, K key, V value)
```

but, when you call it, you write

```
curNode.insert(n, curNode)
```

Am I missing something? It seems to me like this code shouldn't run. I believe you should be calling it as

```
insert(curNode, key, value);
```

Separately, you have

```
boolean x = true;
```

at the start of your insert() method, which can be replaced by return statements to avoid entering the recursive blocks after successfully adding a node. I would change your insert method to this:

```
int result = key.compareTo(curNode.key);
if (curNode.L == null && result < 0) {
    curNode.L = new Node(key, value);
    return true;
}
if (curNode.R == null && result > 0) {
    curNode.R = new Node(key, value);
    return true;
}
if (curNode.L != null && result < 0)
    return insert(curNode.L, key, value);
if (curNode.R != null && result > 0)
    return insert(curNode.R, key, value);
return false;
```

to avoid accidentally calling insert() when you do not need to.

Comment: I made a type when calling insert, It should have been curNode.insert(curNode, key, value).

Answer (score 0):

You forget to use  the return values in these calls of insert:

```
    if (curNode.L != null && result < 0)
        insert(curNode.L, key, value);
    if (curNode.R != null && result > 0)
        insert(curNode.R, key, value);
```

Should be:

```
    if (curNode.L != null && result < 0)
        x = insert(curNode.L, key, value);
    if (curNode.R != null && result > 0)
        x = insert(curNode.R, key, value);
```

But think of eliminating varibale x by using return statements.